# Extending a html component get attributes are not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-component

This is my code for custom webcomponent creation.

```
import S3Uploader from 'containers/S3Uploader';
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  detachedCallback() {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this);
  }

  createdCallback() {
    console.log("This attributes",this.attributes); //Why the attribute length is 0
    const props = this.getAllProps(this.attributes);
    console.log(props);
    const s3Config = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('s3-config')); //This is null
    const handleUpload = eval(this.getAttribute('handle-upload'));
    console.log(s3Config,handleUpload);
    ReactDOM.render(<S3Uploader s3Config={s3Config} handleUpload={handleUpload}/>, this);
  }
  getAllProps(attributes) {
    let props = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
      props[attributes[i].nodeName] = attributes[i].nodeValue;
    }
    return props;
  }
}



document.registerElement('s3-uploader',Component);
```

The problem is attributes length is 0 and all the attributes are null in createdCallback function.

So I am not able to pass the required attributes to react component.

Comment: What is `this` ?

Comment: `this` is the reference to that object

Comment: do that object have `attributes`? and try `console.log(this)` and see whether its `window`

Comment: Yes the component is extending HTMLElement and attributes are part of HTMLElement

Comment: As you mentioned above if `this`  reference to that object in `createdCallback()` ? then what is the issue

Comment: `this.attributes` is logging as empty object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176633/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-deepak-kumar-t-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting to the V1 spec instead of the V0 spec:

```js
//import S3Uploader from 'containers/S3Uploader';
//import React from 'react';
//import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    //ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log("Attribute count",this.attributes.length); //Why the attribute length is 0
    const props = this.getAllProps(this.attributes);
    console.log(props);
    const s3Config = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute('s3-config')); //This is null
    const handleUpload = eval(this.getAttribute('handle-upload'));
    console.log(s3Config,handleUpload);
    //ReactDOM.render(<S3Uploader s3Config={s3Config} handleUpload={handleUpload}/>, this);
  }
  
  getAllProps(attributes) {
    let props = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
      props[attributes[i].nodeName] = attributes[i].nodeValue;
    }
    return props;
  }
}

customElements.define('s3-uploader',Component);
```

```html
<s3-uploader s3-config='{"dog":12}' handle-upload="console.log('testing')"></s3-uploader>
```

I commented out the react code so this would run in the test bed, but this works.

The V0 spec is deprecated and soon to be dead. All components should be written using the V1 spec.